# How to get a email using UID from firebase in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, search

I am trying to get the email using UID.  This is what my firebase database looks like:

[click here for picture of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0vVH.png)

Currently, this is what I'm trying but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
var newEmail = '';
var database = app.database().ref('User/');
database.orderByChild().equalTo(uid).on('value', function(snapshot) {
  newEmail = snapshot.val().email;
})
```

Also, should I add emails to Uid so that there is a hashed snap id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your reference path is incorrect; in your screenshot, you have another parent node `Uid`.

```
var newEmail = '';
var database = app.database().ref('User/Uid');
...
```

Secondly, you are querying `orderByChild` without passing the path parameter, but you should be using `orderByKey` anyway. However, you don't need to query the reference; you know the key of the snapshot you want the value of, so you can create a direct path by interpolating the UID.

```
app.database().ref(`User/Uid/${uid}`).on('value', function(snapshot) {
  newEmail = snapshot.val().email;
});
```

Lastly, you are listening to the reference; if you only require the value once, you may use the `.once` function in the same way, which as the name implies is triggered once.

```
app.database().ref(`User/Uid/${uid}`).once('value', function(snapshot) {
  newEmail = snapshot.val().email;
});
```

Comment: It was the asynchronous part that got me because for two hours, I tried everything including your version, except I was using newEmail outside of the snapshot function as well.  I moved everything inside of the snapshot function and now it all works.